# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\left(A+x^3\right) \left(B+e^x\right)} \, \mathrm dx \quad \alpha = \frac{9}{2},3,\cdots $

Tags: integration

I'm looking for an analytical solution of the following two integrals

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{9/2}}{\left(A+x^3\right) \left(B+e^x\right)} \, \mathrm dx$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^3}{\left(A+x^3\right) \left(B+e^x\right)} \, \mathrm dx$$

with

$$A,B\in\mathbb{R} \land A,B\geq0$$

Wolfram Alpha gives up unfortunately. For

$B=0$

solutions exist.

These integrals have a physics background. They result from the Cronwell-Weisskopf approximation of calculating the energy averaged doping scattering times to get the dielectric function of a doped semiconductor. The usual theory is based on non-degenerate statistics, whereas I'm working on an implementation using degenerate statistics (needed for high doping concentrations). Within this framework the above integrals occur.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty x^2/((1+x^3)(1+e^x))\;dx \approx 0.30690840544564$ is not known to the ISC http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/

Comment: @ron, sorry corrected the wrong tagging

Comment: They are not indefinite

Comment: corrected text, they are of course definite..

Comment: Why this family of integrals? Where do they come from?

Comment: These integrals have a physics background. They result from the Cronwell-Weisskopf approximation of calculating the energy averaged doping scattering times to get the dielectric function of a doped semiconductor. The usual theory is based on non-degenerate statistics, whereas I'm working on an implementation using degenerate statistics (needed for high doping concentrations). Within this framework the above integrals occur.

Comment: @Rainer I would encourage editing your question to include that information - it may make the question more likely to be found by someone with knowledge of those approximations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the expansion $$ \left( {{\rm e}^{x}}+B \right) ^{-1}= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -{{\rm e}^{-x}} \right) ^{k}{B}^{
k}}{{{\rm e}^{x}}}}, B>0,B<1,x \ge 0,
$$ the integral $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^3}{\left(A+x^3\right) \left(B+e^x\right)} \, \mathrm dx  $$ is reduced to the series of the integrals $$\int_0^\infty \frac {(-1)^kx^3 e^{-\left( k+1 \right) x}B^k} {A+x^3}\,dx$$ which are calculated by Maple  in a closed form. See the ouput  [here](http://rapidshare.com/share/598B9AFB200F7E071732688B5C01B31F).

PS. The same with $x^{9/2}$ instead of $x^3 .$

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^3}{(A+x^{3})(B+e^{x})} \, dx
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{A+x^{3}-A}{(A+x^{3})(B+e^{x})} \, dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{B+e^{x}} - \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{A}{(A+x^{3})(B+e^{x})} \,dx
\end{align*}
Same trick can be applied for first integral.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Here is a tip: Use of $\LaTeX$ syntax is so highly recommended in this forum that is is now considered as a *necessity*.

Comment: @sos440 I think your edit is not correct. It should be fraction in first integral I suppose.